# Finding memory leaks using Instruments in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, instruments

i have been using Instruments in Xcode to find out the memory leaks in my app. I was really impressed by this tool but was also a bit dissapointed because, it is a bit difficult to understand the way is shows the leaks. I have posted the line of code  and i request you to go through it once. The instruments tool is showing a memory leak in a line where i din't even alloc the object. i have noticed similar kind of behavior at many other 
lines as well. Also, memory leaks are still being shown by instruments even after releasing a object.... Can anyone help me this please.....

```
NSCharacterSet *trimSet=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\t,\n, "];
NSString *resultString=[currentCharecterString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:trimSet];
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of Instruments report is that the object *allocated on that line* is leaked, not that this line is causing the leak.

You're probably retaining your string somewhere below.

Comment: hi jv42, I dont think i'm retaining the string anywhere below... If at all i retain it anywhere, can you please tell me how and where can i release it

Comment: Are you storing it to a property?